# Context on using available vs accessible

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Consider the following two sentences:

1) Please put the medicine in the living room so that it is **available** to everyone.

2) Please put the medicine in the living room so that it is **accessible** for everyone.

If both sentences are correct, is there any difference in meaning between the two? It seems that *available* and *accessible* are more or less synonyms but can one always be used instead of the other?

Comment: In a check on line, 'available' comes up as a synonym of 'accessible', but NOT *vice versa*.

It seems therefore that if something is 'accessible' it is also 'available'. But the fact of 'availability' does not necessarily make it 'accessible'. 

'Accessible' therefore seems to me to have a more immediate and certain ring about it than mere 'availability'. But I shall be interested to hear what others say. It is an interesting question (+1) and if it is taken up and debated by participants it should prove interesting.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The idea that the site simply 'answers questions' may well be written into its constitution, but it is a long way from what happens in practice. My impression is that that is far more the remit of EL & L. Very few of the senior contributors accept that there is a prescribed form of anything. In view of that how is it possible to speak of 'answers'? In any event, when it gets to the difference between 'available' and 'accessible', I am doubtful as to how one would find an 'answer' except by reasoned discussion.

Comment: @WS2 Dicussion is possible in chat, which is where long comment threads will be moved. If discussion is necessary before writing the answer, please do that in chat, and then write up the answer.

Comment: @WS2 If two words are synonyms, their meanings overlap for a subset of senses. The relationship is symmetric: if A is a synonym of B, B is a synonym of A; they're synonyms. Yes, they may well (in fact will) have senses / contexts where the two can't be swapped over, and yes, one's set of allowable senses may be a near superset of that of the other.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How about if A is a synonym of B, and B a synonym of C. What, if anything, is the relationship between A and C?

Comment: @WS2 If they have an overlap (in usages), they're synonyms, but the fact that A overlaps B and B overlaps C doesn't guarantee that A overlaps C. Venn diagram analysis.

Comment: @WS2 Leaving aside synonymy and hypernymy issues, I certainly agree that " 'Accessible' ... seems to have a more immediate and certain ring about it than mere 'availability'. " Benedictine may well be available if one goes over to Burnley, but that's not very accessible for many people. Libraries are available, but do all have wheelchair access? Bleach is available in our house, but was inaccessible to our daughter until she cracked the child-proof locks at age 3.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure I entirely agree with that. Could the bleach be said to have been *available* to your daughter given that it was *inaccessible*? Similarly with Burnley's Benedictine to the people of Wigan. I think the two words are closer than I would have estimated. But what does seem different is that 'available' is connected to the idea of *supply*, whilst 'accessibility' is connected to an ability to *take up*.

Comment: They're synonyms. Their distributions _do_ overlap. But the 'centres of gravity' of their usage ranges do fall nearer the provision (available) and appropriableness (accessible) ends of the continuum. I suppose it corresponds to the difference between spoon-feeding and facilitating.

Answer (score 7):

Accessible implies that it is not only available but in a place where it can be accessed. Something might be available but not easily retrieved; accessibility implies some ease of retrieval.

Comment: Good answer - but perhaps you can add a couple of definitions (perhaps dictionary citations) to back that up? If I saw that I would definitely upvote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Avail" as a noun means "beneficial effect; advantage, benefit, profit" (n. 1a). To "avail oneself of" something is "to benefit oneself or profit by; to take advantage of, turn to account" (v. 4). A resource is "available" if it's possible to take advantage of or profit by it.

To "access", on the other hand, is simply "to obtain, acquire; to get hold of" (v.2 1a), or "to gain admission to; to enter" (v.2 1b).

The difference, then, is that "available" emphasizes the *benefit of profit* someone may derive from using a resource, whereas "accessible" has no such connotation, and emphasizes the *possibility of obtaining or reaching* something.

In many cases, "accessible" and "available" would both be appropriate, and the choice would only depend on which word's connotation you found most fitting. In the example you give, it's certainly not wrong to speak of the medicine being "accessible" to everyone (incidentally, "accessible to" is more common than "accessible for": see OED "accessible"). In this case, however, I would use "available", because the point is that the medicine is a resource everyone should be able to benefit from; the physical mechanics by which each person gains access to the medicine are irrelevant, provided they can use it.

By contrast, a building with a wheelchair ramp is said to be "wheelchair accessible", not "wheelchair available". The reason is that the issue here is whether a person in a wheelchair can physically get into the building, with no reference to whether entering the building is a source of profit or advantage.

Source: OED

Comment: I'd say that 'available' has been bleached of a lot of the 'beneficial / advantageous' flavour (if I may mix metaphors): a vailable adj.
1. Present and ready for use; at hand; accessible: _kept a fire extinguisher available at all times_.
2. Capable of being gotten; obtainable: _a bedspread available in three colors_. [AHDEL]

Comment: I agree, in some cases the "profit" aspect is pretty faintly felt. But don't you think it's legitimate to say that "available" has in view the goal of making use of something, while "accessible" has in view gaining access to it? So both work in a situation where "profiting from" and "reaching" an item mean basically the same thing, which is why both "kept a fire extinguisher available" and "kept a fire extinguisher accessible" are fine. But you would never say a bedspread was "accessible" in three colors, because we care about the potential of enjoying that good, rather than how you get it.

Comment: Yes. As someone once said, "All words are infinitely polysemous."

Answer (score 1):

Medicine might be available for your children but not accessible to them.  Its availability indicates the possibility and profit of its use by them, while not being accessible indicates their inability to obtain it on their own.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular sentence the two words amount to virtually the same thing.

But they do not mean exactly the same thing.

In a check on line, 'available' comes up as a synonym of 'accessible', but NOT *vice versa*.

It is possible for something to be *available* but *inaccessible*. And despite the synonymous nature I would also argue thet it is possible for something to be *accessible* but *unavailable*.

'Accessible' seems to me to have a more immediate ring than mere 'availability'. But I shall be interested to hear what others say. It is an interesting question and if it is taken up and debated by participants it should prove interesting.

Comment: In another online check, each word is used in the definition of its synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility often refers to an availability specific to people with physical disabilities. For example, a restaurant may be available to the public. But without a ramp, it will not be accessible to an individual in a wheel chair.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

**Scenario 1:** a health care worker in a low-income community may be present to provide care for her catchment population, but the health post in which she is located is difficult to get to because of its rural location (i.e. care is available but not accessible).

**Scenario 2:** The health post is built and visible in the village. However, because the health care worker has many villages to attend to as part of her assigned duties, she is not always present at the post (i.e. care is theoretically accessible but not available).

Your question seems to revolve around the concept of equity. You could put the medicine in the room on the highest shelf, so that only the tallest people (or those economically advantaged-enough to buy a stool) would be able to access it. Technically the drugs are available to everyone. The second case would for example require that the medicine be put in the center of the room, so that everyone may access it. The concept of availability (i.e., the scenario of accessible but not available) is rendered moot by the fact that *the question assumes that the medicine is already present in the room and is therefore by default available.*

These definitions of course are specific to a public health context and as such this concept of availability/accessibility may not be applicable in other situations.